# Do we say "L'Incontro Pasta" and if so why?

Tags: grammar

"The pasta meeting" in Italian would be "L'Incontro Pasta".
I am aware of the fact that adjectives should come last, e.g., "la pasta verde".
But why do we say "L'Incontro Pasta" instead of "la pasta incontro"?  Or maybe we could say "L'Incontro di Pasta"?

Comment: As all translation questions, this should come with more context. What is it that you want to say exactly? Is this a conference of pasta producers? The name of a restaurant? The nickname of a rendezvous between an Italian politician and a local one? A physical object called "meeting" somehow made out of dough? Maybe these [biscuits](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51qgWJwwVnL.jpg)?

Comment: I agree with @FedericoPoloni: in the way it's stated now, we can't understand your question.

Comment: «"The pasta meeting" in Italian would be "L'Incontro Pasta".» Actually, it wouldn't. Not only it is not good Italian; it's unfathomable what it should mean.

Comment: It is the name of a restaurant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the name of the resturant, I'm not sure it is translatable while still meaning the same thing.
Literally it should be "L'incontro della pasta".

Comment: mining = meaning?

Comment: yeah... sorry. It happens when you write in two different languages. It's not an excuse anyway..

Comment: It could also be translated as _Incontro di pasta_.